# c_str() seems to eliminate some integers in converting from C++ string class

Tags: c++, string

I am having difficulty converting a string I am reading from a file into an integer.

The output of my code below is:

```
Line Raw: 118
Line C:
Elem: 0

Line Raw: 121
Line C:
Elem: 0

Line Raw: 32
Line C: 32
Elem: 32
```

Any idea why converting to c_string seems to eliminate some integers?

The actual code that is causing this is below:

```
vector<int> compressed;
string encodedLine;
while (getline(inputFile, encodedLine)) {
    cout << "Line Raw: " << encodedLine << endl;
    cout << "Line C: " << encodedLine.c_str() << endl;
    int elem = atoi(encodedLine.c_str());
    cout << "Elem: " << elem << endl;
    compressed.push_back(elem);
}
```

The dump of the input file:

```
118
121
32
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for all the quick answers! The problem was indeed the NULL character in the file. I noticed that the string 118 was showing as length 4. After doing the HexDump, I saw "00 31 31 38" and that confirmed this. Thanks!

Any suggestions for how to write to the file (which I control in another class in the program) without prepending NULL?

Comment: Is it your real code? In other words: with that code you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: yes... this is my real code.

Comment: What does `encodedLine.size()` give you?

Comment: You've given us code and output results but no indication if your **input data is actually valid**. Include your input data in your question.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - I included the dump of the input file. Also - I check that with the line: cout << "Line Raw: " << encodedLine << endl;

Comment: Is this a UTF encoded file? I'm betting if you do a hexdump of the input file you're going to see a null character at the beginning of the first two lines.

Comment: try something like cout<< "line raw: "<<encodedLine<< "end-marker" << endl;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your input file has null characters in it.

`std:string` has no problem holding a null character, but the C string functions treat it as the end of a string, of course.

Comment: This was indeed the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the standard library (what a surprise) nor in this piece of code (a somewhat smaller surprise). It works perfectly:

[image]